# What is the "cursor" device provided by Wacom tablets?

Tags: wacom, input-devices, graphics-tablet

`xinput` yields the following (irrelevant bits removed):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
...
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen stylus             id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen eraser             id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen cursor             id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos Pro M Pad pad                id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Intuos Pro M Finger touch           id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
...
```

"Pen stylus" and "Pen eraser" are the pen input, "Pad" is the buttons on the tablet itself, and "Finger touch" is self-explanatory. But I can't figure out what "Pen cursor" is. Nothing registers when I test it with `xinput test 17`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/How-Wacom-tablets-work), the cursor device is a "mouse-like device compatible with some tablets". It's not clear to me why this is referred to as "mouse-like" rather than simply a "mouse", but it appears that my model is compatible with one of Wacom's mice.

I don't own one of these mice, so I can't test this hypothesis, but I'll make this the provisional answer until someone can confim it.